# Calculate lag between two time series as a function of time

Tags: python

Dear science programmers:

I have two different time series, both of them in the same time scale. The two series look very similar, but they are lagged from each other. The lag is irregular through time.

I'm looking for a way for python or a python package to compute the lag between the two time series as a function of time. I.e., to get at each time the lag between the time series. I would greatly appreciate any help. Here is a piece of the time series if it's useful:

[edit] A lag is the smallest time difference between same values in the time series. It has time units. For example, the lag between a cosine and a sine function is pi/2.

```
time,series1,series2
0,0.358436019,0.3188888067
100,0.4200473934,0.2975307174
200,0.4816587678,0.2761726281
300,0.5432701422,0.2548145388
400,0.6048815166,0.3126306018
500,0.6038827258,0.3934880929
600,0.519889065,0.474345584
700,0.4358954041,0.5552030751
800,0.3519017433,0.6360605662
900,0.2679080824,0.5366397394
1000,0.1839144216,0.4279857816
1100,0.1105732484,0.3193318238
1200,0.1153503185,0.210677866
1300,0.1201273885,0.1104286187
1400,0.1249044586,0.1162674576
1500,0.1296815287,0.1221062965
1600,0.1344585987,0.1279451354
1700,0.1392356688,0.1337839744
1800,0.1842811502,0.1396228133
1900,0.2369968051,0.197331632
2000,0.2897124601,0.2586226391
```

Comment: You don't have any of the exact same values, so I suppose you'd need to approximate your values to a curve first. But I'm not a data scientist. Try breaking down the problem. How would you do it on paper, on at least on a graphing calculator?

Answer (score 0):

Read the CSV into a [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) DataFrame, then you can simply subtract.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df['lag'] = df['series1'] - df['series2']
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    time   series1   series2       lag
0      0  0.358436  0.318889  0.039547
1    100  0.420047  0.297531  0.122517
2    200  0.481659  0.276173  0.205486
3    300  0.543270  0.254815  0.288456
4    400  0.604882  0.312631  0.292251
5    500  0.603883  0.393488  0.210395
6    600  0.519889  0.474346  0.045543
7    700  0.435895  0.555203 -0.119308
8    800  0.351902  0.636061 -0.284159
9    900  0.267908  0.536640 -0.268732
10  1000  0.183914  0.427986 -0.244071
11  1100  0.110573  0.319332 -0.208759
12  1200  0.115350  0.210678 -0.095328
13  1300  0.120127  0.110429  0.009699
14  1400  0.124904  0.116267  0.008637
15  1500  0.129682  0.122106  0.007575
16  1600  0.134459  0.127945  0.006513
17  1700  0.139236  0.133784  0.005452
18  1800  0.184281  0.139623  0.044658
19  1900  0.236997  0.197332  0.039665
20  2000  0.289712  0.258623  0.031090
```

This also makes it easy to get the average lag, among other things:

```
>>> df['lag'].mean()
0.006529929428571425
```

Comment: Hmmm... Thanks but df['lag'] will give me the difference between two time series. What I'm looking for is a lag, which would be in time units. It's similar, but not quite the same.

Comment: @juan I'm not sure what you mean. Please [edit the question](/posts/68930430/edit) and add your desired output.